# How to remove an extra column at the start in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid that is getting dynamically generated.Issue is i see a extra column blank though small in size at the start of datagrid.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="individualGrid" Margin="0,2,0,0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=individualFilter, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" 
              Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="500"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=deptFilter, Path=SelectedItem.Individuals.View}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_UH_individualGrid" ColumnWidth="*" 
              MinColumnWidth="140" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGeneratingColumn="IndividualGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

There was also one extra blank column at the end which i removed using ColumnWidth="*" but not sure how to remove this one at the start.Please help

### SOLUTION

### Setting HeadersVisibility="Column" resolved the issue.Thanks to Sajee!

Comment: An image in your question would be great in this case.

Comment: share your code, how are you binding the grid?

Comment: I cannot upload the same because i need atleast 10 rep. points. XAML code already shared.

Comment: then share the link of image in your question..

Comment: Image shared: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1d2f3a9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set this to your datagrid ,

```
HeadersVisibility="Column"
```

Comment: @Sandeep There should be two array up and down on the left side of the answer, click up if you want to upvote the answer and there should be a tickmark as well, just click it if you need to mark as answer

Comment: @Sandeep To mark as an answer you dont need 15 rep points, just click the tick mark